# sqlite android сравнить числа

Tags: android

Создана одна таблица. В ней два поля:

```
public void load(int one, int two)

{

    ContentValues se = new ContentValues();
    se.put(COLUMN_ONE, one);
    se.put(COLUMN_TWO, two);
    mDB.insert(DB_TABLE , null, se);

}


public Cursor getAll() {

    return mDB.query(DB_TABLE,  null, null, null, null, null, null ");

}
```

каким образом можно сравнить числа  в таком порядке:2 с 3,4 с 5 и т.д

1____________2

3____________4

5____________6

Comment: какая должна быть выборка в курсор: отобрать все строки, в которых второй столбец одной строки равен первому столбцу другой?

Comment: смысл такой в бд храняться даты выборка идет по дням недели с понедельника по воскресение строки нужны все.нужно дату второго столбца одной строки сравнить с датой первого столбца второй строки и т.д .

Comment: в реляционных БД нет понятия первой, второй и тд. строки